# Unity AudioManager PlayerPrefs Slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the below audiomanager for my project. Whenever I run a game from the "Play" button in Unity - I can change the volume via slider and the settings are being saved and they load when I exit and play again via Unity's "Play" button.

However can you please explain to me why I cannot do this when I go to the PlayGame and then I go back to the main menu via "restart" button in my game? When I do that - the slider is 100% charged and it doesn't save/load new  setings.

Any comments / feedback is much appreciated!

```
public static AudioManager AMInstance;
[SerializeField] Slider volumeSlider;

private void Awake()
{
    if (AMInstance != null && AMInstance != this)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        return;
    }
    AMInstance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
private void Start()
{
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("musicVolume"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVolume", 1);
        Load();
    }
    else
    {
        Load();
    }
}

public void ChangeVolume()
{
    AudioListener.volume = volumeSlider.value;
    Save();
}

public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("musicVolume", volumeSlider.value);
}

public void Load()
{
    volumeSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("musicVolume");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` before you navigate to another scene. It does get called by default `OnApplicationQuit`, but since you are just setting a the float, you might need to explicitly call the Save function.

[Unity's documentation for PlayerPrefs.Save](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html)